# my listview does not print out my array list after importing it from my file

Tags: java, android, file, android-arrayadapter

The listview does not show the string array file and I cant seem to view string that the user input

```
public class ReadActivity extends ListActivity {
String[] mStringArray;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


 ListView listview = getListView();

    FileWritter fl = new FileWritter();
    List<String> mStringList = fl.loadlist2("DiaryNames.txt",this);
    mStringArray = new String[mStringList.size()];
    mStringArray = mStringList.toArray(mStringArray);


   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
   (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mStringArray); 

   listview.setAdapter(adapter);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
```

So far this is the code where I think has the problem for loadlist2 so this is for the list to import file from diarynames.txt which has input from another function is

```
    public List<String>  loadlist2(String title, Context context)
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(title));

        String mystring;
        while ((mystring = in.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(mystring);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occurred" + e);
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @BabyYakuza! Is the FileWritter same as FileWriter class in Android or is it something you have written (probably extending the FileWriter class)?

Comment: Hi @Ashish It is an additional class that I made

Comment: @BabyYakuza what does load list2 method do?? can you show that code??

Comment: @BabyYakuza whats inside DiaryNames.txt??

Comment: Can you post that contents also so it could help

Comment: @Jeeva it is a string of user input so for now there is nothing inside it

Comment: @BabyYakuza what about load list2??if you give all inputs we could easily solve it out

Comment: @Jeeva I just shared it sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't get
`System.out.println("Exception Occurred" + e);` ?

Answer (score 0):

@BabyYakuza - Before I start with my answer, I would like to ask you; **can you please post the contents of the file DiaryNames.txt? If you don't have it, can you tell us the format of the text in this file? Also, where is this file present (I mean in your directory structure)? This is because, everything else you are doing seems to be okay.**

I ran through your code in my IDE. I am using the following contents for DiaryNames.txt

```
Ashish Raghavan
Sushant Shivaprasad
Piyush Murari
Mohan Nair
Tushar Nair
```

When I run through your code,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(title));

    String mystring;
    while ((mystring = in.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(mystring);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception Occurred" + e);
}
return list;
```

I get the correct output of 5 strings as in the number of names mentioned in the file DiaryNames.txt.

Also, you don't need the context argument in loadlist2 as you are not using that anywhere. Anyhow, here is my pastebin code [Main method](https://pastebin.com/3f75Cr3S) and [FileWritter.java](https://pastebin.com/3NaCksBN). 
Please modify the path for the file DiaryNames.txt if you use this code. Also, I have not passed anything in the loadlist2() method because it is always the filename DiaryNames.txt and the Context variable, which is unused in the method.

Most probably, the format of the text in DiaryNames.txt is not what you are expecting. If you can post some sample content of the file DiaryNames.txt, it would really help us help you.